# How can a node access another node in another gateway?

Tags: networking

Well the situation may seem to be complex but here it is.

I have a computer X. It is connected to gateway 1. Another computer Y is connected to gateway 2. Gateway 1 and 2 are themselves connected to a super gateway G which is connected to Internet.

This is actually the setup of my college network. The college uses a gateway (G) to distribute IPs to hostel rooms (Each room gets one IP). Since I have 2 computer (My PC and my Raspberry Pi (X)), I need to use a network switch (gateway 1) to connect to internet. Similarly my friend in the adjacent room has a network switch which connects his laptop (Y). The Raspberry Pi (X) has LAMP server and the laptop Y wants to access its content. How is this possible? What address should be entered in the web browser? How will the browser know which address does it points to?

Another question is : If I directly connect my laptop to Gateway G, then I have to login first to access the Internet. Can I setup my network switch in such a way that it automatically logs into the Gateway G so that I don't have to login when my computers are connected? My network switch is D-Link model AES-1005A.

Answer (score 0):

First, a switch is not a gateway (router). There is a big difference. Each device you connect to your switch is getting its own IP address from DHCP, else it wouldn't work.

You don't get one IP address per room since that is not how DHCP works, There may be a switch between Router G and your rooms that limits the number of MAC addresses per port. If that is the case, you are out of luck, otherwise your friend should try to connect to the address assigned to your Pi by DHCP.

Network switches only operate at layer-2, so any upper-layer protocols like the login are completely transparent to it, and you cannot have it log in for you. Your Pi may actually need to log in, too, to get an IP address from DHCP.

You seem to be trying to bypass the network policies or security of a network that doesn't belong to you. In many jurisdictions, this is a crime (usually, a felony), so you should tread very carefully.

Also, since this doesn't involve programming, it is actually off-topic here, and you should really ask on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Very thanks for the reply. We have a single LAN port in our rooms. So we have to use a switch. However a LAN splitter doesn't work. We can connect multiple devices through a switch but not through a LAN splitter. When we joined our hostel we were asked to reconfigure our IP to 192.168.137.xx where xx is our room numbers. All my 3 laptops have the same settings and connected to switch and the switch to the single LAN port in my room. If the switch doesn't act as a gateway then all the 3 devices are carrying the same IP. How is it possible?

Comment: All three devices do not have the same IP address. Each device will be assigned an individual IP address within the same subnet.